# Retrieving User Token (found in Access Token Tool) via code C#/PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Facebook app and I can retrieve the App Token by calling

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

as specified on the [Authenticating as an App](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) page. I see this app token is also available in the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) page along with a User Token for the app. I need the User Token in order to do a /USER_ID/accounts on users that have already approved my app with the manage_pages permissions.

Basically I wish to post to a users Facebook page when they submit an article to my app. Some users are in locations where Facebook is blocked, thus I can't use the regular Javascript SDK.

**Edit 1**: I understand the concept of user access tokens and retrieving them via the SDK with the OAuth redirect. My question is in regards to the **User Token for an app** as seen in the Access Token Tool page, not a user access token (which requires client access to Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a user token without using the javascript SDK, you need to authenticate the user using the [OAuth dialog redirect](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/). Essentially, you prompt the user to fetch a code from Facebook that you can exchange for an access token. At this point you should store the access token and re-use it for all requests that require authentication. Keep in mind though that you will need to detect when the token is expired or invalidated, and if so you will need to re-issue the authentication redirect & token exchange process.

Comment: Thanks for the replay Jesse, but my dilemma is that some users don't have access to Facebook and thus the OAuth dialog redirect is not possible. This is why I wish for my app to do the authentication on behalf of the user after they have authorized my app and after their initial user access token has expired